# Dynamic message for custom exception annotated as ResponseStatus

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to provide dynamic message for my custom Exception like in code snippet below:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Entity not found")
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public EntityNotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

But always when I throw it like shown below:

```
throw new EntityNotFoundException("User entity not found");
```

in the browser, I get the message "Entity not found" instead of "User entity not found".

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 15):

I was stuck on this, But I just removed the reason side of the @ResponseStatus and It works, so your code should be like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
public EntityNotFoundException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
 }
}
```

And now you can set custom message by the constructor

Comment: this dont work for me